# JavaScript file type with extensions and file size

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Dear Sir this code working fine.But i need JavaScript validation with file type extensions and file size .When ever i upload a file same time it check file size and file extension so that it produced desired result.Please help me to correct the code i will be thankful to you.looking positive response

```js
$('#image-file').on('change', function() {
 var numb = $(this)[0].files[0].size/1024/1024;
numb = numb.toFixed(2);
if(numb > 2){
alert('to big, maximum is 2MB. You file size is: ' + numb +' MB');
} else {
alert('it okey, your file has ' + numb + 'MB')
}
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="image-file">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use lastIndexOf to get the last \ as an index and use substr to get the remaining string starting from the last index of \

```
    // find elements
       $('#image-file').on('change', function() {
 var uploadedFile = $(this)[0].files[0];

const name = uploadedFile.name;
console.log(name);
  const lastDot = uploadedFile.name.lastIndexOf('.');

  const fileName = name.substring(0, lastDot);
  const ext = name.substring(lastDot + 1).toLowerCase();
  // you can add extension here which allowed to upload
  if(['png','gif','jpeg','jpg'].includes(ext)){
     alert('file is image');
  }else{
  alert('file is not an image');
  return false;
  }
  
 var numb = uploadedFile.size/1024/1024;
numb = numb.toFixed(2);
if(numb > 2){
alert('to big, maximum is 2MB. You file size is: ' + numb +' MB');
  return false;
} else {
alert('it okey, your file has ' + numb + 'MB')
}
        })
```

Comment: dear sir i need validation check when i upload file it check file extension and file size if some body not fulfill these two things it not allow him to upload file.